# How to load XML to List<string>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to use the contents of an XML file as the data source to a List

**My XML**

```xml
<History>
  <Articles>
    <Article></Article>
  </Articles>
  <Names>
    <Name>One</Name>
    <Name>Two</Name>
    <Name>three</Name>
    <Name>four</Name>
  </Names>
</History>
```

I have next code:

```cs
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fs);
    listName = doc.Descendants("Names").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
}
```

but I got collection with single element - "OneTwothreefour"

How I can do it ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes`?

Comment: Changing that `"Names"` to `"Name"` (i.e. `Descendants("Name")`) should make it work, but `XmlSerializer` may be easier for anything more complex

Comment: I´d also suggest to use the `XmlSerializer`  and deserialize the entire xml into a class. This safes you from annoying casting, as everything already is strongly-typed.

Comment: I would avoid using value which will fail if null.  Try instead : listName = doc.Descendants("Name").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng: `x` will never be null in this case. When do you think `Descendants()` returns a sequence that contains a null value? It might return an *empty* sequence, but that's a different matter.

Comment: The element will never be null, but the innertext will be null(or empty).  The element can have attributes with no innertext.

Comment: instead of this approach follow my answer that actually simple and easiest way @Vladimir

Comment: @jdweng: And how do you think casting the element to `string` is different from taking `Value` in that case? Hint: [it's not](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Private.Xml.Linq/src/System/Xml/Linq/XElement.cs#L1341)

Comment: @HiteshAnshani: I definitely don't see having to create an extra class and mess around with a serializer as simpler than a one-liner. There are cases where it's appropriate, but if the only requirement is "get the text values if the Name elements in the document" then `doc.Descendants("Name").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()` really is hard to beat.

Comment: I've seen cases where replacing Value with a cast worked.  Not sure it the Linq Library was change so Value now works same as a cast.

Comment: @jdweng: "I've seen cases where replacing Value with a cast worked" That's the case where the element reference you're dealing with might be null, but that's not the situation here.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok Got it.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
List<string> names = doc.Descendants("Name").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```